# Force all queries within a batch to get data as at the start of the batch

Tags: sql-server, isolation-level

In SQL Server, when executing a batch of SELECT queries, is it possible to force all queries run during the course of a batch to get data as it was at the start of the batch, to ensure consistency between results of data is changed while the queries are running?

Comment: There are other options for result set stability too. Caching the results on application level, reporting tables that are updated on batch basis and more. To get good advice, edit the question and explain with more details what kind of business problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this by executing the batch within a transaction running at the `SNAPSHOT` isolation level.

This requires enabling the `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` database option, [setting the isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql) for the current session to `SNAPSHOT`, then starting an explicit transaction.

See the [product documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide#behavior-in-summary) for details.